# Understanding proof that multiplicative inverses exist in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers, cauchy-sequences

**Context**: For this course, the real numbers were constructed using Cauchy sequences, i.e., each real number is the equivalence class of a Cauchy sequence of rational numbers.

I'll only post the relevant part of the proof here, as its not used again and the rest is clear to me.

**The proof**: Suppose $\left[\left(x_i\right)\right]\neq \left[\left(0\right)\right]$ where $(0)=(0,0,0,\ldots)$. This implies that $\exists \varepsilon>0$ such that $\forall N$ $\exists n>N$ such that $\left|x_n\right|>\varepsilon$. But $x_n$ is Cauchy, so $\exists M$ such that $\forall k,\ell > M$, $\left|x_k - x_{\ell}\right|<\varepsilon/2$.

Now take $m>\text{max}\{M,N\}$. Then $\left|x_m\right|\geq \varepsilon/2$.

For context again, he's doing all this to show that $\left(x_i\right)$ is eventually non-zero.

**My problem**: For one, I don't understand how $\left|x_m\right|\geq \varepsilon/2$ follows from what he stated beforehand. I tried rearranging and trying to get it from the Cauchy criterion but I don't see it.

Second, I don't understand why this even needs to be shown. If $\left[\left(x_i\right)\right]\neq \left[\left(0\right)\right]$, then doesn't it follow that $\left(x_i\right)$ is eventually non-zero? Since the statement isn't that $\left(x_i\right)\neq (0)$, but rather that *none* of the sequences equivalent to $\left(x_i\right)$ equal *any* of the sequences equivalent to $(0)$. It should follow naturally that $\left(x_i\right)$ must be 'eventually non-zero', no?

**Note**: I can't ask the professor because this course isn't actually running at the moment. I'm studying ahead for it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Actually it's more than just showing that $(x_i)$ is eventually non zero. The sequence $x_i=1/i$ is eventually non zero... in fact... it's *never* zero. And yet, in the construction of the real numbers, the sequence $x_i=1/i$ represents zero.

Comment: @Lee Mosher That's true, but since $x_i =1/i$ represents zero, it is contained in $[(0)]$, isn't it? So my point still stands.

Comment: I don't know what the point is that you want to stand... but... the point you should pay attention to is this: What distinguishes the Cauchy sequences that *do* represent zero from the Cauchy sequences that *do not* represent zero?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now. Just to check, he's saying that while a sequence such as $x_i=1/i$ is also eventually non-zero, we want our sequence to be non-zero in the sense that *every* element past a certain 'point' is greater than a fixed number (here $\varepsilon/2$), which is not true for the aforementioned $1/i$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's a good way of putting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m>M$.
As described, there exists $n>M$ with $|x_n|>\epsilon$. As $m$ and $ n$ are $>M$, we have $|x_m-x_n|<\epsilon/2$.
Then $|x_m|\ge |x_n|-|x_m-x_n|>\epsilon/2$ by triangle inequality.

Note that “sequence is eventually non-zero” ($\exists N, \forall n>N, x_n\ne0$) is not enough; we need “does not converge to $0$” aka. “Is not a zero sequence”. For example, the sequence given by $x_n=\frac 1n$ is eventually (in fact, immediately) non-zero, but $[(x_k)]=[(0)]$.

Answer (score 2):

First, there appears to be an error in what you wrote. You wrote the expression $\max(M, N)$, but you did not define $N$ in this context. $N$ does occur earlier on the page, but it is quantified over, and $\max(M, N)$ occurs outside the scope of the $\forall N$. I will instead assume instead that $m > M$.

> For one, I don't understand how $\left|x_m\right|\geq \varepsilon/2$ follows from what he stated beforehand.

Take some $n > m$ such that $|x_n| > \epsilon$. Then $|x_n - x_m| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Now $x_n = (x_n - x_m) + x_m$, so $\epsilon < |x_n| = |(x_n - x_m) + x_m| \leq |x_n - x_m| + |x_m| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} + |x_m|$. We used the triangle inequality for one of these steps.

Then $\epsilon < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + |x_m|$, and therefore $\frac{\epsilon}{2} < |x_m|$, as required.

> Second, I don't understand why this even needs to be shown. If $\left[\left(x_i\right)\right]\neq \left[\left(0\right)\right]$, then doesn't it follow that $\left(x_i\right)$ is eventually non-zero?

It does indeed follow. However, a sequence can have all its elements nonzero and still converge to $0$. So the fact that all but finitely many elements of $x$ are nonzero is actually *not* what we’re trying to show. We’re trying to show there is some $w > 0$ such that all but finitely many elements of $x$ have absolute value at least $w$. This is the result we really need to show that the inverse of $[x]$ exists and can (almost) be constructed pointwise.

Comment: About the error, I copied this word for word from what he wrote, so he might've made a mistake there. As for your working, I understand every step except your very first one: why can we take $n>m$? I thought his statements only guarantee that $n>N$, not that $n>m>\text{max}(M,N)$. Could you explain please?

Comment: Never mind, I see it now. Thank you for the answer.